# How I can run 'cmd' command inside rake process using Rails 4

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, cmd

I want to save data after running below command.

```
  ip = '12.33.44.55' #it will be dynamic.

  traceroute -q 1 -n ip
```

But problem is how can I run this command inside rake task.

Normally it runs in command line of Linux.

Any gem or ruby library to do this?

Any help please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It possible to run any shell command with magic quote "`" in any ruby code.

```
ip = '12.33.44.55'
`traceroute -q 1 -n #{ip}`
```